# Apache Nutch - Solr Clean vs deleteGone

Tags: solr, search-engine, nutch

I'm using Apache Nutch for crawling and Solr for indexing.

My question is: What's the difference between using `bin/nutch clean` and using the flag `-deleteGone` in `bin/nutch index`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both ways have the same effect - removing all 404s, redirects, etc. from the Solr index (or other indexes, eg. Elasticsearch).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One question though: I noticed that cleaning using the `bin/nutch clean` takes much longer than using the `-deleteGone` flag. 

Is it because cleaning with `-deleteGone` only deletes "_gone_" documents that were discovered in the **last** segment, and `bin/nutch clean` deletes all the "_gone_" documents discovered in **all** the segments?